# How to get Data from April To Present Date in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on financial domain. So I want data from April To May.

Suppose Current Month IS June then I only want April to June of this year and it should group by year and month.

And If Suppose Current Month is February then I want details from last April to Jan i.e. April-2013 to Jan-2014

I have got the solution through CTE If i only run CTE Part of the query it is working perfectly fine 
This Part of query..

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate AS datetime = getdate();
    DECLARE @FirstDayInCurrentMonth AS datetime = DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(day, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate);
    DECLARE @LastApril AS datetime = DATEADD(month, -(DATEPART(month, @FirstDayInCurrentMonth) + 8) % 12, @FirstDayInCurrentMonth);

    WITH Periods AS (
        SELECT @LastApril AS [Period]
      UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, [Period])
        FROM Periods
        WHERE [Period] < @FirstDayInCurrentMonth
    )
    SELECT 
            DATENAME(month, [Period]),
            DATEPART(year, [Period]),  

    FROM Periods
```

But I want **sm.is_approved** cloumn also work as above query.  when I jon other table with above CTE expression. I want proper group by of **sm.is_approved** column.

I only have the doubt that what will be the condion for joining the other table.
**Please give men the proper condition for the below bold part of the query.**

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate AS datetime = getdate();
DECLARE @FirstDayInCurrentMonth AS datetime = DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(day, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate);
DECLARE @LastApril AS datetime = DATEADD(month, -(DATEPART(month, @FirstDayInCurrentMonth) + 8) % 12, @FirstDayInCurrentMonth);

WITH Periods AS (
    SELECT @LastApril AS [Period]
  UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, [Period])
    FROM Periods
    WHERE [Period] < @FirstDayInCurrentMonth
)
SELECT 
        DATENAME(month, [Period]),
        DATEPART(year, [Period]),  
        MONTH(sm.is_approved) as [MONTH],
        isnull(sum(ISM.selling_price * siim.qty),0) as Price,  
        isnull(sum(((tm.tax_amount*(ism.selling_price * siim.qty))/100)),0) as Tax,  
        isnull(sum((ism.selling_price * siim.qty) + (((tm.tax_amount*(ism.selling_price * siim.qty))/100))),0) as TotalPrice 
FROM Periods

**LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Sell_Order_Master as SM on sm.is_approved >= DATEADD(MM, 1, @LastApril)**
left outer join RS_Sells_Invoice_Info_Master as SIIM  on sm.sell_order_no = SIIM.sell_order_no  
left outer join RS_Inventory_Selling_Master as ISM on ISM.selling_product_id = SIIM.selling_product_id  
left outer join RS_Tax_Master as TM on Tm.tax_id = SIIM.tax_id  
group by 
DATENAME(month, [Period]),
DATEPART(year, [Period]),
MONTH(sm.is_approved)
```

Can anyone tell me that how to what will be the condition for above query ie bold part of the above query

ie this part I only want this condtion to be true
 **LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Sell_Order_Master as SM on sm.is_approved >= DATEADD(MM, 1, @LastApril)**

Comment: hey why you dislike my question

Comment: You can add a "month" table, and left join on it (not the downvoter by the way).

Comment: not able to understand the requirements. Is there any Year comparison required?

Comment: can you please see my query I have already joined that column but if there is no data on that month then it will not print april month

Comment: no. Mr vikas I have tables which is showing tax & price. If i have not sell any product on april then how can I get the april coulmn with 0 sells and 0 tax. so tht i can display that month's data as well

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question. You have my upvote.

Comment: how can i get the list of total months from april even though i have not sold any thing can anyone help

Comment: Use full outer join instead

Comment: do all your months have values? If your months are null they will be replaced by 0 and your sql wont print it.

Comment: No I dont have values for all the months thats why I am not able to disply that month & also full outer join is not useful

Comment: jonny,It will print 0 Bcoz it is default value that I have given

Comment: Hey whoever did downvote then please help to solve this if you are thinking this is too easy then give reply

Comment: @Hardik I'd like to help you. Please, provide sqlfiddle with data samples.

Comment: hey sorry  but i dod not got you

Comment: @Hardik, if you forget to address me using `@Horaciux` I wont get the message. About using SQL Fiddle is easy. Select SQL 2008. Then make a script for creating all tables involved and then add some data samples via inserts.

Comment: it means i have to copy the script of the tables and paste into the sql fiddle right

Comment: @Hardik yes, and then click buid schema, make sure no error rises, and then copy URL and share with us.

Comment: Horaciux Can you help me on chat session

Comment: adrianm can you help me for this

Comment: @Hardik ok, where is it? never chated here

Comment: No,adrianm but you helped me for the above query remember but the moment i joined CTE expression i am not getting proper O/P. Please see above query & please help me

Comment: I think we need to see sample starting data and desired results.  With a name like `is_approved` I'm expecting a `Boolean` type (ie, true/false), but you seem to be using it as a date/time/timestamp type.  You also likely need some link between `Periods` and the rest of your tables, or your results won't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to understand your question, but I'm not sure if I understood :

CTE retrieves all months since last April and you want to display informations linked to `RS_Sell_Order_Master` (Invoices, Inventory and Taxes...). This should mean, you have to display for all months since last April thoses details.

So maybe you just simply need to make match `Periods` CTE months and years with `RS_Sell_Order_Master` months and years.

So you just simply needs to do that :

```
FROM Periods as P
left outer join RS_Sell_Order_Master as SM 
    on MONTH(sm.is_approved) = MONTH(P.[Period])
    and YEAR(sm.is_approved) = YEAR(P.[Period])
```

Here in the full code :

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate AS datetime = getdate();
DECLARE @FirstDayInCurrentMonth AS datetime = DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(day, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate);
DECLARE @LastApril AS datetime = DATEADD(month, -(DATEPART(month, @FirstDayInCurrentMonth) + 8) % 12, @FirstDayInCurrentMonth);

WITH Periods AS (
    SELECT @LastApril AS [Period]
  UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, [Period])
    FROM Periods
    WHERE [Period] < @FirstDayInCurrentMonth
)

SELECT 
        DATENAME(month, [Period]),
        DATEPART(year, [Period]),  
        MONTH(sm.is_approved) as [MONTH],
        isnull(sum(ISM.selling_price * siim.qty),0) as Price,  
        isnull(sum(((tm.tax_amount*(ism.selling_price * siim.qty))/100)),0) as Tax,  
        isnull(sum((ism.selling_price * siim.qty) + (((tm.tax_amount*(ism.selling_price * siim.qty))/100))),0) as TotalPrice 
FROM Periods as P
    left outer join RS_Sell_Order_Master as SM 
        on MONTH(sm.is_approved) = MONTH(P.[Period])
        and YEAR(sm.is_approved) = YEAR(P.[Period])
    left outer join RS_Sells_Invoice_Info_Master as SIIM  
        on sm.sell_order_no = SIIM.sell_order_no  
    left outer join RS_Inventory_Selling_Master as ISM 
        on ISM.selling_product_id = SIIM.selling_product_id  
    left outer join RS_Tax_Master as TM 
        on Tm.tax_id = SIIM.tax_id  
group by 
    DATENAME(month, [Period]),
    DATEPART(year, [Period]),
    MONTH(sm.is_approved)
```

If i'm wrong correct me, or if you have another issue just leave a comment.

Comment: my cte expression is working correctly but only the condition you have corrected that is not working

Comment: ... Is my solution working for you ? I tried to explain my mind, but you seems to not understand it. Try to join on Month and Year, as I suggested to you, if it does not work, try to explain to me what is your issue.

Comment: Can we turn on the chat If you want can we send the chat's link

Comment: I spend 2hours on searching how to create a chat, I failed at it. If you need more help, just explain (context, issue, exemple).

Comment: thanks alot for your valuable time I also don't know how to start the chat but its true that we can chat with each other on stack overflow but how that I dont konw Sir.

Comment: Sir Can you give me your email Id

Comment: You need 100 rep to open a chat room.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but seeing at the tables I think your joins should be as follows:

```
FROM Periods
LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Sell_Order_Master as SM on sm.is_approved >= DATEADD(MM, 1, @LastApril)
INNER join RS_Sells_Invoice_Info_Master as SIIM  on sm.sell_order_no = SIIM.sell_order_no  
INNER join RS_Inventory_Selling_Master as ISM on ISM.selling_product_id = SIIM.selling_product_id  
INNER join RS_Tax_Master as TM on Tm.tax_id = SIIM.tax_id
```

And Grouping as:

```
GROUP BY
DATEPART(year, [Period]), 
DATENAME(month, [Period]),
MONTH(sm.is_approved)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below instead of your first three lines, I basically turned the date into a Date without the time which will probably join onto your periods table properly

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate AS datetime = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(getdate() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
DECLARE @FirstDayInCurrentMonth AS datetime = DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(day, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate)
DECLARE @LastApril AS datetime = DATEADD(month, -(DATEPART(month, @FirstDayInCurrentMonth) + 8) % 12, @FirstDayInCurrentMonth)
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to compare between dates e.g. compare Feb-2014 and Apr-2014 if false the you have to subtract one from the year part of April.
You can use functions to compare and substring the date and subtract the date.

Answer (score -1):

First thing, the way you generate dates, you should remove the Hour part using:

```
DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0,@CurrentDate))
```

Second, try using Inner Join instead of left join.

Still I would suggest you give us better idea of how the data is stored. Possibly add the basic schema and test values in the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)

So I can execute the query and get better idea of what you want.

Comment: hey I dont know how to put my question on SQL Fiddle

Comment: It's a test platform. Like I created a schema and added some query, that way "http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1b9a"

Comment: it means i have to create all the tables and have to insert values in to it

Comment: put some test values, and only those columns that are the basic requirement for this query. So one can understand the dependency.